# Correspondência de chave e valor de duas listas de dicionários

Tags: python, estrutura-de-dados, dicionário

Dado duas listas de dicionários como -

```
poo = [{
      "xmin":10,
      "ymin":100,
      "xmax":70,
      "ymax":120,
      "text":"fish",
}]
```

E também,

```
foo = [{
      "class":"Animal",
      "percent":88.25,
      "box_points":[30, 90, 80, 110]
}]
```

Para produzir uma saída como:

```
poofoo = [{
    "class":"Animal",
    "text":"fish",
    "percent": 88.25,
    "box_points":{
          "xmin":10,
          "ymin":90,
          "xmax":80,
          "ymax":120}
]}
```

> Sabendo que `box_points` na lista de dicionários `foo` também está no formato `xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax`. Esses pontos são coordenadas de caixas detectadas por sistemas de detecção distintos (as duas listas não possuem o mesmo tamanho)

**Como eu poderia acessar os elementos aninhados, comparar as boxes e mesclar os elementos?** A ideia é mesclar elementos espacialmente pertos, nesse exemplo, o limiar é de 10 unidades (x,y).

Eu já tentei assim:

```
def boxOverlap(box1, box2):
    try:
        if(box1[0]<=box2[2]-10 or box1[0]>=box2[0]) \
          and (box1[1]<=box2[3] or box1[1]>=box2[3]):
            return True, [min(box1[0], box2[0]),
               min(box1[1], box2[1]),
               max(box1[2], box2[2]),
               max(box1[3], box2[3])]
        else:
            return False
    except TypeError:
        print(f"{message_error}")

final_json = []

for el1, el2 in zip(foo, poo):        
    el1_box_format = [el1['x_min'], el1['y_min'], el1['x_max'], el1['y_max']]
    
    if(boxOverlap(el1_box_format, el2['box_points'])):
        final_json.append({"class":el2["name"],
                           "text":el1["text"],
                           "confidence":el2["percentage_probability"],
                           "boxpoints":None
                          })
```

Note que, criei uma função que retorna um booleano caso as caixas se interseccionem. Mas o problema é que quero comparar todas as boxes vizinhas e do jeito que fiz, usando `zip(foo, poo)` ele opera em pares que não necessariamente estão pertos.

**Edição**: Vale lembrar que o critério de mescla das boxes é simples, basta pegar a menor abcissa (x) e ordenada (y) para `xmin` e `ymin` e a maior abcissa e ordenada para `xmax` e `ymax`, respectivamente.

Comment: Obrigado por me lembrar, o critério é simplesmente pegar as coordenadas mínimas das boxes para `xmin` e `ymin` e as máximas para `xmax` e `ymax`

Comment: Eu cheguei até aqui https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/BoxOverlapping#main.py , agora explique com mais clareza qual o problema pois aqui por exemplo *"Como eu poderia acessar os elementos aninhados, comparar as boxes e mesclar os elementos? A ideia é mesclar elementos espacialmente pertos, nesse exemplo, o limiar é de 10 unidades (x,y)."* parece que são várias atividades de comparação que deseja fazer entre os elementos do array resultante, mas não dá para pontuar o que quer fazer. Poderia esclarecer?

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por partes.

Em primeiro lugar, foque em como resolver isso para dois dicionários, sem pensar em listas. Dá para fazer isso de forma quase que declarativa, apenas usando as funções `min` e `max` para conferir quais os menores/maiores valores mínimos/máximos, respectivamente:

```
poo = {
      "xmin":10,
      "ymin":100,
      "xmax":70,
      "ymax":120,
      "text":"fish",
}
foo = {
      "class":"Animal",
      "percent":88.25,
      "box_points":[30, 90, 80, 110]
}
new_dict = {
    'class': foo['class'],
    'text': poo['text'],
    'percent': foo['percent'],
    'box_points': {
        'xmin': min(poo['xmin'], foo['box_points'][0]),
        'ymin': min(poo['ymin'], foo['box_points'][1]),
        'xmax': max(poo['xmax'], foo['box_points'][2]),
        'ymax': max(poo['ymax'], foo['box_points'][3]),
    }
}
```

Tendo isso feito, crie uma função que aceite dois dicionários e retorne um novo dicionário com a estrutura do `new_dict` acima:

```
def get_new_dict(poo, foo):
    return {
        'class': foo['class'],
        'text': poo['text'],
        'percent': foo['percent'],
        'box_points': {
            'xmin': min(poo['xmin'], foo['box_points'][0]),
            'ymin': min(poo['ymin'], foo['box_points'][1]),
            'xmax': max(poo['xmax'], foo['box_points'][2]),
            'ymax': max(poo['ymax'], foo['box_points'][3]),
        }
    }
```

Agora, aplique essa função para cada par de dicionários nas suas listas, usando `zip` para iterar sobre elas lado-a-lado:

```
poo_list = [{...}, {...}, {...}, ...]  # sua lista de dicionários poo
foo_list = [{...}, {...}, {...}, ...]  # sua lista de dicionários foo

new_dict_list = []
for poo, foo in zip(poo_list, foo_list):
    new_dict = get_new_dict(poo=poo, foo=foo)
    new_dict_list.append(new_dict)
```

A lista `new_dict_list` contém seu resultado esperado.

Comment: Já fica com up. Me parece, porém não está claro, que o AP também quer encontrar intercessões entre os retângulos gerados usando os valores da chave `box_points` como coordenadas duma diagonal, de todos os elementos contidos no `new_dict_list`. Da minha parte a orientação seria o AP desdobrar a pergunta em duas, uma pergunta sobre como fundir as listas de dicionários e outra pergunta sobre as intercessões entre as geometrias geradas. Claro isso se o AP esclarecer que realmente minha interpretação faz sentido e se a comunidade concordar.

Comment: Verdade @AugustoVasques, não havia prestado atenção nessa parte da pergunta. Concordo que parecem ser duas perguntas distintas.

Answer (score -1):

Seria isso que você quer?

```
new_dict = foo[0]
new_dict['text'] = poo[0]['text']
new_dict['box_points'] = {i:poo[0][i] for i in poo[0] if i!='text'}
```

Resultado:

```
{'class': 'Animal', 'percent': 88.25, 'box_points': {'xmin': 10, 'ymin': 100, 'xmax': 70, 'ymax': 120}, 'text': 'fish'}
```